# 'The folder could not be opened' Lubuntu 12.04 64-bit error

Tags: lubuntu

I am getting a error window stating LAUNCH ERROR  while trying to open other partition (ntfs , ext4) from desktop with description as follows.

> Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote
>   application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy
>   blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
>   connection was broken.

My network connection is working properly and it is couple of days Fresh installation alongside Ubuntu 12.04
Also posting a screen shot, though not a major problem but now i am getting it quite often.

[image]

P.S : I am guessing it is Mostly related to file manager [ thunar 1.2.3]

Answer (score 0):

Solution in this post should help:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11816590&postcount=4

Works for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.